# Hi I am getting an error whenever i run Artisan in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting this error whenever i run `php artisan serve` or any other command with `php artisan`.

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                                                                                                                                          

 Type error: Argument 2 passed to 
 Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of 
 Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in 
  /Volumes/Dev/Development/crewlogix/aplica _student/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 64
```

Comment: This may help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312693/laravel-5-php-artisan-syntax-error%22

Comment: check laravel logs and after solve run again artisan

Comment: @Mohammadb i have checked the logs this is same as console

Comment: put route file code in question

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your route file, please look into route file.

Comment: I Know it happens whenever there is an error in routes. but i have nt found any syntax error in it. i am using PHPstorm but there is no syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are not using any **url()** or **asset()** or other helpers functions inside your configuration files